# centering buttons in a form

Tags: jquery, css, forms, center

I want to center two buttons in a form. I got a wrapper div around them and tried margin: 0 auto and float: left, but it's not working.

```
.button_container {
width: auto;
min-width: 834px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
}
```

[image: buttons]

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqeq/LerVW/)

Would be perfect if the buttons would be centered under the textarea. Is this possible?

**UPDATED:**

Thank you everyone, I used Sachins Fiddle as it worked the best for my situation.

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LerVW/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do couple of things like 
Remove `float:left`, add `text-align:center` and most importantly remove `min-wdith` as it force to have that width of container that make it not center aligned.

```
.button_container {
    width: 100%;
/*  min-width: 834px;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LerVW/5/)

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LerVW/9/)

this work's fine

[image]

```
.button_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Another style :
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LerVW/10)**

[image]

```
 .box_wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 325px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: it is just what I have said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center;` to `.button_container` making it:

```
.button_container {
width: auto;
min-width: 834px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
text-align:center;
}
```

This will center everything inside the button container making your buttons centered as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say that I approve of using the `<table>`, but it would be a lot of work to change now so you might as well use it.  Just add another row that contains the buttons.

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <button name="submit" class="submit_btn" type="submit">Absenden</button>&nbsp;
        <button name="reset" class="submit_btn" type="reset">Zur&uuml;cksetzen</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This looks good to me on its own, but you can also left padding to the second `<td>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/LerVW/2/

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do if you want the buttons centered under the `textarea` is moving your `button_container` to a new row on the table...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/WFh9S/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.button_container {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 834px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The border was simply added to illustrate the DIV size.

http://jsfiddle.net/LerVW/3/

Comment: How do you figure? It's centered within the div. I'm not sure what browser you're using but I just checked it in Chrome, FF, and IE10.  If you're going to downvote me and leave a comment, at least make it constructive.

Comment: No, it's not because of the min width. http://jsfiddle.net/AgrP8/3/ is centered within the div.

Comment: Actually it IS centered within the div.  The minimum width of that div just happens to be 834px because that's what he set it to be.  If he wants to remove that he can.